# Return values from columns using a row with (duplicated) primary key to different rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerquery, m

I need a way to return data from rows that are defined by duplicating key, and return the data in these rows in different columns in a separate sheet with unique key.

I am working with a large file with 20,000+ data with multiple sheets and need to produce the below outcome for one of the data:

Sample data:
[image: Raw Data]

[image: Desired output in a separate sheet]

Is there any ways that Excel can do this for me? I am not familiar with VBA if that's the way but I can still try with more assistance.

Methods tried:

1. =IFS
2. Power Query (merge and append)
3. index and match

Thank you so much for your ideas! This is taking me a lot of time and I don't even know how to ask google to get to a solution...

Comment: Is it maximum 4 rows for a book or can there be more? Can I ask why you want the data transformed to that? Only ask as there maybe a better solution to your desired need without transforming the data.

Comment: Hello! Thanks so much for trying to help! There are indeed more than 4. This data is a summary for further mapping. I’m welcoming better alternatives!

Comment: I would recommend not going down this path as you will have an indeterminate number of columns etc... The way you have your data structured currently is preferred for further analysis as it is vastly easier to perform calculations on rows than it is on columns. Given your sample Raw Data, what is your end objective/goal?

Comment: Basically to make an analysis out of column A against the respective columns C-G

Comment: Based on that, you should leave your data as it. Instead load it into Power Query, and create two tables (queries). Table Book (Book Id, Book Name - and remove duplicates), and Table BookScore (Book Id, Score A, Score B, Score C, Score D, Score E). Load these two queries to the Data Model. Then go to the Data Model and add a relationship between the two. Now you can add measures or calculated rows for your needed calculations. You could achieve the same without the Data Model and use XLOOKUP etc... Research Data Model in Excel for more.

Comment: sure excel can do it without vba but it not so easy; the solution in my mind now is by aggregate function to determine the row no and use it inside index function; that's after counting exactly the max number of duplications to fill all cells in the new sheet with the combined function

Comment: Are all the sheets in the workbook similar to the sample data? Some with more, some with less columns or is it always C-G? Do the scores need to be added together for each book (per scoring letter) or what needs to happen with them?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77371860/group-and-transpose-data-in-excel

Comment: @Notus_Panda the scores are not to be summed but to be expanded individually. Sam - I tried data model but doesn’t return a plain expanded metadata with the scores for data analysis. I will try the let function in the post you mentioned!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powerquery, using M

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Book#", "Book title"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Book#", "Book title", "Attribute"}, {{"data", each 
    let #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type)
    in Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Index", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Attribute", "Index"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged")
    , type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Value", "Merged"}, {"Value", "Merged"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded data",{"Attribute"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns1"[Merged]), "Merged", "Value")
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank youuuuu it works!!! But I will need to separate my data into smaller chucks (around 10,000 each) to run the query. I’m using 365 32-bit, there’s a memory issue there running all entries.

Comment: Happy to help. Im surprised you are having data issues with it, but ok.  Note this output is a terrible format for data to be in

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution using formulas, however we may want to wait for someone to post a power query solution.

```
=LET(a,A1:G11,
     u,UNIQUE(DROP(TAKE(a,,2),1)),
     d,HSTACK(u,
              DROP(
                   REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(u)),
                   LAMBDA(x,y,
                          VSTACK(x,
                                 TOROW(FILTER(DROP(a,1,2),DROP(TAKE(a,,1),1)&INDEX(DROP(a,1),,2)=INDEX(TAKE(u,,1)&INDEX(u,,2),y)))))),
                   1)),
     e,DROP(TAKE(a,1),,2),
VSTACK(
       HSTACK(TAKE(a,1,2),
              TOROW(e&SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(d)/COLUMNS(e)))),
       d))
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try everything in this post this weekend! I tried data model but the result isn’t what my boss wanted - to compile a complete metadata for data analysis