# Group and transpose data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transpose

First, I apologize for posting this question among answers.

As for the question, I have an Excel data I need to transpose from columns into rows.

[image: excel data]

I need to group the same data from column A with corresponding data from columns B and C. I'll need new table with these data:

```
(row1) 0041001000053, 2006.10.17, 12, 2007.05.15, 12, 2018.07.15‚  12
(row2) 0041001000061, 2006.10.17, 12 
(row3) 0041001000126, 2006.12.18, 6, 2007.12.18, 6
```

Is it possible to extract it this way, without using Power Query?

I tried using Pivot, but the dataset is too large (over 50k entries). Simple transpose won't work as well, because I need unique entry in row 1 and specific ones in other rows.

Answer (score 0):

With ***Microsoft-365*** excel, you can utilize `REDUCE()` function. Try-

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A6),DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(A2:A6),LAMBDA(a,x,IFERROR(VSTACK(a,TOROW(FILTER(B2:C6,A2:A6=x))),""))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Harun.

But I'm using Excel 2013 at work and I get message that function isn't valid. Do you have any alternate solutions?

Comment: @Sabre so make a list of the ID and sort, then use a logical test to replace duplicates with blanks, then do another sort and you end up with a unique list... Takes some steps...

Comment: Thank you, Mike. That seems to do the trick. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This two formulas works on older Excel versions.

In cells D2 and E2

```
=IF($A2=$A1,"",IF($A2=OFFSET($A2,COLUMN(D2)-3-(COLUMN(D2)-COLUMN($D2))/2,0),OFFSET($A2,COLUMN(D2)-3-(COLUMN(D2)-COLUMN($D2))/2,1),""))

=IF($A2=$A1,"",IF($A2=OFFSET($A2,COLUMN(D2)-3-(COLUMN(D2)-COLUMN($D2))/2,0),OFFSET($A2,COLUMN(D2)-3-(COLUMN(E2)-COLUMN($E2))/2,2),""))
```

Then copy the two cells(together) to the right as long as needed.

Then copy the row (D2 to D end of fill) down.

Then a unique filter on the data column A.

Test result: (from row35)
[image]